# How can I verify if a wallet owns an NFT?

Tags: wallets, nft

I'm working on a project where I will need to verify if a wallet owns a certain NFT. I will ask the users to do a transaction from the wallet that contains the NFT, so I will have their wallet address.

Is there any way that I can then check if they own the NFT that they say they own?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

IERC721 has a `ownerOf` function, you can use that.